# Prove that for all $R>0$ there is an $N$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}\neq 0$ for all $|z|<R$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> I want to show that for all $R>0$ there is an $N$ such that $$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}\neq 0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$ for all $|z|<R$.

My idea was the following:

Let us fix $R>0$ and define $\Omega=\{|z|<R\}$ which is clearly open and connected. Define the analytic sequence of functions $$f_N(z)=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}$$ on $\Omega$ and remark that $f_N(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in \Omega$ and $N$. Now let $K\subset \Omega$ be a compact subset then since $z^n$ is continuous on $K$ there is $M$ such that $|z|^n\leq M$. Therefore $$\max_{z\in K}\left|\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right|=\max_{z\in K}\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\right|\leq\max_{z\in K}\sum_{n=N}^\infty \left|\frac{z^n}{n!}\right|\leq\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} \max_{z\in K}|z| ^n\leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}M\stackrel{N\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 0 $$which shows us that $f_N$ converges uniformly to $e^z=:f(z)$. Then using Hurwitz theorem we get that $f(z)=0$  or $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in \Omega$. But since for $z=1\in \Omega$ $f(1)\neq 0$ we get that $f(z)\neq 0$. Therefore we can always find $N$ such that $(1)$ is satisfied.

Does this work so?

Comment: @AdamRubinson At z=0, function=1.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I also don‘t think it is false but my prove do not hold since $f_{1}(-1)=0$ so I need to find another one

Comment: You should be able to tackle this by noting that for large enough $N,\ e^z \approx \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|z|^n\le M$ for all $n$ is false for $|z|\gt 1$.  Theorem is provable using convergence to $e^z$ which has no zeros.  The main thing is for $z\lt -R$, where for all $n\gt N$  with large enough N, the polynomial is close enough to $e^z$ to be $\gt 0$.